# Why are there no longer any performance timings shown in the gutter of JavaScript files in Chrome DevTools when I take a performance recording?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

There used to be light-yellow timings (e.g. "2341ms") shown next to the line-numbers in the source panel after taking a performance recording. I'm wondering what happened to this feature? It would show a darker yellow for the parts of the code that were the most costly. Has this feature been removed? Or is there something I need to do to enable it in more recent Chrome versions?

Comment: I see these only when using "JavaScript Profiler" panel from devtools menu -> More tools.

Comment: Ah, thanks! You're right. Seems like it doesn't work for WebWorker scripts, which is what I wanted it for, but I guess that's a separate question.